# Show an image(in a table) with a dropdown (no javascript)

Tags: html, css

For a project, we have to make a page where users can customize a product. I wanted to achieve this through a dropdown where users can choose their car color. This has proven to be quite hard without the ability to use divs and javascript. The goal is to show a hidden table-cel when a color is selected in the dropdown menu. I've been trying to do this through "option:checked" and "option:active" but it just shows all of the images in the table. Thanks in advance for taking a look :)!

```css
     .kleur1,.kleur2,.kleur3,.kleur4,.kleur5{
            display: none;
        }
        #kleur1.kleurfilter:checked ~ table,tr,td.kleur1,
        #kleur2.kleurfilter:checked ~table,tr,td.kleur2,
        #kleur3.kleurfilter:checked ~ table,tr,td.kleur3,
        #kleur4.kleurfilter:checked ~ table,tr,td.kleur4,
        #kleur5.kleurfilter:checked ~ table,tr,td.kleur5{
            display: table-cell;
        }
```

```html
   <main>
    <table>
        <tr class="kleurPerson">
            <td class="kleur1"><img src="../media/customize/rsz_black.jpg" alt="Zwarte mercedes amg gt4"></td>
            <td class="kleur2"><img src="../media/customize/rsz_blue.jpg" alt="Blauwe mercedes amg gt4"></td>
            <td class="kleur3"><img src="../media/customize/rsz_red.jpg" alt="Rode mercedes amg gt4"></td>
            <td class="kleur4"><img src="../media/customize/rsz_white.jpg" alt="Witte mercedes amg gt4"></td>
            <td class="kleur5"><img src="../media/customize/rsz-silver.jpg" alt="Silvere mercedes amg gt4"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <select name="kleur" id="kleur">
        <option class="kleurfilter" id="kleur1" value="Midnight black">Midnight Black</option>
        <option class="kleurfilter" id="kleur2" value="Sky blue">Sky blue</option>
        <option class="kleurfilter" id="kleur3" value="Matte Red">Matte red</option>
        <option class="kleurfilter" id="kleur4" value="Slick white">Slick white</option>
        <option class="kleurfilter" id="kleur5" value="Silver">Silver</option>
    </select>
    <label for="kleur">Mercedes</label>

</main>
```

Comment: You need javascript for this. You could do it with css if it were possible to make the image a child of the checkbox, however `input` elements are self closing and do not contain content, which makes this not approachable with pure css.

Comment: That's bad news, for some ridiculous reason I am not allowed to by the teacher

Comment: If javascript is required to be omitted, it sounds kinda like you are being set up for failure. It would theoretically be possible using css `not` pseudo selectors, however you would need to alter your dom tree significantly. Either way in an actual production environment, any layout that managed to achieve this as you describe would be convoluted and unmaintainable, and you should probably chew out your teacher for setting you up for bad practice intentionally.

Comment: ^ Logical operations belong in the codebase. Design considerations belong in the stylesheet. Making logical operations part of css violates the order of responsibilities.

Comment: Not really your fault if you didn't design the assignment. It bears mentioning to your teacher/professor though.

Comment: Ouch that's really sad, I think the best thing that I can do then is the dumb it down to the point that there are just 5 images where the user can choose from

Comment: thanks for the help and sorry for the waste of time

Comment: Maybe put the image in the select option body

Comment: It would need to be pretty tiny though to look right

Comment: it might be worth a try

Comment: @JelleSpruyt are you sure you need to have the html structure as you created? can't we modift that? Can we use checkboxes or radio buttons?

Comment: you can change the html structure if you want, radio buttons do sound interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with the approach you are taking since there is no parent selector in CSS and the `table` is not a general sibling (`~`) of the selected `option`.

If you're happy to restructure your html you can use labels to toggle radio buttons like this messy demo:

```css
.kleur1,
.kleur2,
.kleur3,
.kleur4,
.kleur5 {
  display: none;
}

#kleur1:checked~table td.kleur1,
#kleur2:checked~table td.kleur2,
#kleur3:checked~table td.kleur3,
#kleur4:checked~table td.kleur4,
#kleur5:checked~table td.kleur5 {
  display: table-cell;
}

input[name=kleur] {
  display: none;
}

.options label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.options label:hover:before {
  display: block;
  content: attr(data-name);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 2px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <input type="radio" name="kleur" id="kleur1" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="kleur" id="kleur2" value="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="kleur" id="kleur3" value="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="kleur" id="kleur4" value="4" />
  <input type="radio" name="kleur" id="kleur5" value="5" />
  <table>
    <tr class="kleurPerson">
      <td class="kleur1"><img src="../media/customize/rsz_black.jpg" alt="Zwarte mercedes amg gt4"></td>
      <td class="kleur2"><img src="../media/customize/rsz_blue.jpg" alt="Blauwe mercedes amg gt4"></td>
      <td class="kleur3"><img src="../media/customize/rsz_red.jpg" alt="Rode mercedes amg gt4"></td>
      <td class="kleur4"><img src="../media/customize/rsz_white.jpg" alt="Witte mercedes amg gt4"></td>
      <td class="kleur5"><img src="../media/customize/rsz-silver.jpg" alt="Silvere mercedes amg gt4"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="options">
    <label for="kleur1" style="background:black" data-name="Midnight Black"></label>
    <label for="kleur2" style="background:blue" data-name="Sky blue"></label>
    <label for="kleur3" style="background:red" data-name="Matte red"></label>
    <label for="kleur4" style="background:white" data-name="Slick white"></label>
    <label for="kleur5" style="background:silver" data-name="Silver"></label> Mercedes
  </div>
</main>
```

P.S. I see no reason for your images to be in a table.

Answer (score 1):

According to your structure, you cannot do it via pure CSS and HTML as CSS has not parent or backward selector. I have modified the HTML and have used radio buttons to achieve the same in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saksham_malhotra/7tgbxw3m/)

I have used the `+` immediate sibling selector

Comment: Thanks so much change a bit of code tho , but it worked!!